# Delete files from NSCachesDirectory programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

If I downloaded files in `NSCachesDirectory` programmatically in my app, is it also possible to delete the files programmatically?

Comment: @iPatel's answer is quite good. Other wise you can do enumeration in that folder and delete all files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There may be many way for get full path of **File from Directory**, following is one of them.

```
NSArray *myPathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *mainPath    = [myPathList  objectAtIndex:0];

mainPath = [mainPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:DirectoryName];
```

Here **mainPath** is Full Path of File.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:mainPath];

if (fileExists)
{
     BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:mainPath error:&error];
     if (!success) NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

}
```

Comment: That will delete a file from the `Documents` directory, not the `Caches` directory.

Comment: ok, we can replace the `NSDocumentDirectory` by `NSCachesDirectory` to delete from cash. I'm right, am not I?

Comment: @trojanfoe .. Sory friend .. be honestly i dont know about how to get file path from  NSCachesDirectory..so please check my edit.

Answer (score 5):

I think this snippet should work for you:

```
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *fileArray = [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:nil];

for (NSString *filename in fileArray)  {
    [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:[directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] error:NULL];
}
```

Comment: How about sub-directories?

Answer (score 3):

combining anurag and iPatel

we get this final code that will clear all from the caches directory

```
    NSArray *myPathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *mainPath    = [myPathList  objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *fileArray = [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:mainPath error:nil];
for (NSString *filename in fileArray)  {
    [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:[mainPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] error:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete specifically `UIWebView` cache then this could be helpful:

```
for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {
     if([[cookie domain] isEqualToString:someNSStringUrlDomain]) {
         [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
     }
}
```

Comment: the Question is to Delete files from NSCachesDirectory, not clearing the Cookie