# Clear ios app storage data?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

So I'm able to delete image cache's, but is there a way to delete files in the storage for the app? For example, if you go to Settings > General > Storage And iCloud Usage > Manage Storage  and then find your app. I want to clear this data, because it keeps building up. Any insight on this?

This is what I currently have:

```
        var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var cache = System.IO.Path.Combine(documents, ".config", ".isolated-storage", "ImageLoaderCache");
        foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(cache))
        {
            //older than or 3 days, delete
            DateTime fileCreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file);
            if ((DateTime.Now - fileCreationDate).Days >= 3)
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(file);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `NSCachesDirectory` not `MyDocuments` :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064854/delete-files-from-nscachesdirectory-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing cached images in Document (`<Application_Home>/Documents`) folder, Store it in Cache (`<Application_Home>/Library/Caches`) folder.

According to [iOS data Storer Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html)  If you are storing something in document directory, it means you want to backup it on iCloud. 
so when data is store in document directory- its getting uploaded to iCloud. and thats why its displaying in iCloud storage.

Comment: It's not always obvious in Xamarin, how to do that, but I definitely agree. We figured out the issue wasn't the iCloud at all, and more to do with a DLL in our app that was huge thus making the app huge, and which reflected the size in the storage page. I do agree though and will upvote your answer for it is correct.